# JQuery mobile with jade not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, express, pug

I'm trying to use jquery mobile with jade & express. I'm a bit new to jade, it would be nice to help me figure out whats going wrong here. I'm using the standard Jquery mobile 1.3 files included with the zip download in a folder called `pre`

I have two files a layout:

```
doctype 5
html
  head
    title= title
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(name='viewport',content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    meta(name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable',content='yes')
    meta(name='apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style',content='black')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/pre/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/pre/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/pre/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.0.min.css')
    script(src='/pre/jquery-1.9.1.min.js')
    script(src='/pre/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js')

  body
    block content
```

And my content:

```
extends layout
block content
  div#page1(data-role='page')
  div(data-theme='a',data-role='header')
    h3
      | Header
  div(data-role='content')
    a(data-role='button',href='#page1')
      | Button
    a(data-role='button',href='#page1')
      | Button
    a(data-role='button',href='#page1')
      | Button
  div(data-theme='a',data-role='footer',data-position='fixed')
    h3
      | Footer
```

The problem I get:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indentation in `content.jade` is wrong. Indent everything below `div#page1(data-role='page')` and it works just fine

```
extends layout
block content
  div#page1(data-role='page')
    div(data-theme='a',data-role='header')
      h3 Header
    div(data-role='content')
      a(data-role='button',href='#page1') Button
      a(data-role='button',href='#page1') Button
      a(data-role='button',href='#page1') Button
    div(data-theme='a',data-role='footer',data-position='fixed')
      h3 Footer
```

As you can see you could even simplify your code by not using the pipes `|`

Comment: Thanks, Jade is a bit new to me, I used http://www.htmltojade.com/ to convert it from html I guess it gave me something a bit off